# How to dismiss "setError()" from an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, navigation-drawer, dismiss

I have an application of conversion, it uses navigation drawer but when you don't type the amount it throws an error with the method "setError()" for the EditText that is not filled, however there is a but, 
when I open the Navigation Drawer **the message of the error remains on the screen** on the navigation drawer and I don't know **how to dismiss the error** when the drawer is opened.

Comment: You can clear focus of EditText after second time touch Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever navigation drawer is opened Just call

```
editText.setError(null);
```